# anime.js running lights animation

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I try to do an animation which should look like "running lights".

https://plnkr.co/edit/TiL6DLSLVYxLT63kBXfr?p=preview

As you can see in my Plunker the first run looks good, but after a while the lights get out of sync. Obvioulsy anime.js adds the delay again each loop iteration. How can I prevent that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animateText(container, el) {
        $(container).each(function() {
            var thisContainer = $(this);
            var initialColor = $(this).find(el).css("color");
            var delay = 0;
            $(thisContainer).find(el).each(function() {
                anime({
                    targets: $(this).get(0),
                    color: ["#ff0", initialColor],
                    duration: 1000,
                    loop: true,
                    delay: delay*50
                });
                delay++;
            });
        });
    }
    animateText('ul', 'li');
});
```

Comment: Here's another (not working) try: https://plnkr.co/edit/zZgCBYbVJJoh6iwBq4IY?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to run it inside `anime` function.. I tried to loop as you did in `$.each` but I think that the issue is either `loop` property that adds sometime or each loop item somehow..

the good thing is that you can access index of the item inside `delay` and duration like this:

```
delay: function(el, i) { return 250 + (i * 100); },
```

see this example if that can help you..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function animateText(container, el) {
    var alltrans = anime({
      targets: '#parent li',
      color: [ '#008000', '#ff0', '#008000'],
      loop: true,
      duration: function(el, i) { return 50 + (i * 15); },
      delay: function(el, i) { return 50 + (i * 50); },
    });
  }
  animateText('ul', 'li');
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

li {
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<h1>Anime.js Runing light</h1>
<ul id="parent">
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much(!), but I would like to have only one light "on" at the same time.

Comment: I edited it a little,, just play with the timinig in delay/duration,, shoots bunch of combinations :)

Answer (score 1):

@Kremsimir answered my question well, however I think I have found a solution which is slightly better for my special case. The reason is that my solution is independend from the number of items.

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {
  function animateText(container, el) {
    $(container).each(function() {
      var elIndx = 0;
      var thisContainer = $(this);
      var initialColor = $(this).find(el).css("color");
      var timeline = anime.timeline({loop:true});
      $(thisContainer).find(el).each(function() {
              timeline
                .add({
                    targets: $(this).get(0),
                    color: [initialColor, "#fc3d1b", initialColor],
                    duration: 400,
                    loop: true,
                    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
                    direction: 'alternate',
                    offset: (elIndx == 0 ? null : '-=350') // afterglow effect
                })
            elIndx++;
      });
    });
  }
  animateText('ul', 'li');
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

li {
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>

<h1>Anime.js Runing light</h1>
<ul>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
  <li>&#9608;</li>
</ul>
```